# Only first command executed & redirected to the console window

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, command-prompt

I tried to build a console application using tkinter. But after entering first command, it only executed. But then nothing happens.

Here, I have added **while** loop, so the execution process would go, but still having the same issue. Have I made a mistake?

````
import sys
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import font
from tkinter.font import *
import subprocess
import threading
from threading import Thread``

consl = Tk()
consl.geometry("1200x380")
consl.resizable(1, 1)
consl.configure(background='black')

cmd_OP = Canvas(consl, width=1000, height=500, background="black")
cmd_OP_viewer = Text(cmd_OP, width=700, height=350, background="black", foreground="green")

cmd_OP.create_window((0,0), window=cmd_OP_viewer, anchor=NW)
ScBar = tk.Scrollbar(orient="vertical", command=cmd_OP_viewer.yview, background="grey")
cmd_OP_viewer.configure(yscrollcommand=ScBar.set)
cmd_OP_viewer.pack(side=TOP, expand=True, fill=X)``

#Font for all output & other operations.
helv9 = font.Font(family='Helvetica', size=9, weight=tkinter.font.BOLD)

#input of the console are being set.
l1 = Label(consl, text=os.getcwd(), background="black", foreground="white")

entry = Entry(consl, background="black", foreground="white")
entry.pack(side=BOTTOM, anchor=SW, expand=TRUE, fill=X)
entry.insert(0, '')
entry.delete(0, END)
entry.pack()

l1.pack(side=BOTTOM, anchor=SW, expand=TRUE)
cmdOP = subprocess.check_call(entry.get(), shell=True)
entry.bind("<Return>", (lambda event: (get_entry())))

cmd_OP.pack( )


def run_win_cmd():
    result = []
    try:
        process = subprocess.Popen(entry.get(),
                                   shell=True,
                                   stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                   stderr=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=False)
    except:
        process = os.system(entry.get())
    for line in process.communicate():
        result.append(line)
    errcode = process.returncode
    for line in result:
        data = "".join(map(bytes.decode, result))
        return data
    if errcode is not None:
        raise Exception('cmd %s failed, see above for details for :: \n', entry.get(), process)

def get_entry():
    while TRUE:
        if entry.get() != "exit":
            cmd_OP_viewer.insert(END, str(run_win_cmd()))
            cmd_OP_viewer.config(state=DISABLED)
            entry.delete(0, END)
            break
    else:
        os.system(exit())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    consl.mainloop()```
````

Comment: What do you expect this program (in the current state) to do? Have you already tried debugging it?

Comment: What did you try before the `while True` loop? What exactly is your problem? With what did you try as input? We need more information. (Without the `while True` loop it worked for me)

Comment: The `while TRUE` loop will never exit, because `entry.get()` will never return a different value since the `while TRUE` loop never gives tkinter a chance to process events.

Comment: Bryan sir, actually, this is a small program, which is suppose to be like command prompt/ terminal application. So, I set a label & text input box, where I put command & then it execute through ``subprocess.Popen``. As per the requirement, it successfully executes the first command but later on, whatever I put into text field, it responds the same. No execution redirection happen. 

But, `exit` command is taken & close the window. 
Kindly help me, that all other command would executed & redirect the output to the specific field.@Bryan @Megaing

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try adding a button to submit the entry because while loops with tkinter dont go together so try doing something like

```
btn = Button(consl, text="Submit", command=get_entry)
btn.pack()
def get_entry():
    if entry.get() != "exit":
        cmd_OP_viewer.insert(END, str(run_win_cmd()))
        cmd_OP_viewer.config(state=DISABLED)
        entry.delete(0, END)
        break
    else:
        os.system(exit())
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, Sir. Actually **First command** got executed successfully & also redirected to the GUI panel. But after that nothing happen. I mean no other command is going to be executed. Hence I tried to use `While == True` to re-execute those commands & redirect it to the next screen. But still having the same issue. Kindly help me on this issue. 
Sorry for my bad english.
Thanks in advance.